# Spring context:property-placeholder not loading properties

Tags: spring, properties

I have a Spring config file with one bean. The bean has 2 properties that are populated from a properties file. I am using the following config in my Spring file to copy the values in but it does not seem to be working.

```
   <context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true"
    system-properties-mode="NEVER" 
    location="classpath:my.properties"/>
```

The weird thing is - this has worked before. Can anyone tell me why this would not be successful in copying the properties across?

I know the infomation given is scant. I'll add elaborate if needs be.

Comment: so wheres your properties file ?

Comment: @MikePatel - It's on the classpath.

Comment: and an example of where you use them if its ok ?

Comment: <bean id="myStub" parent="serviceParent" p:serviceInterface="uk.com.MyClass" p:wsdlDocumentUrl="${paf.service.url}?wsdl"/>

Comment: paf.service.url is set in a properties file as follows: service.url= localhost:5000/my-service/cxf paf.service.url= ${service.url}/our-services

Answer (score 3):

Try the `classpath*:` prefix. And try giving the relative path to the conf file, and make sure it is really on the classpath (note that WEB-INF is not on the classpath - the classpath of a webapp starts at WEB-INf/classes (and lib))

Comment: Works, thank you! But what's the difference between the notation with asterisk and without?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that without it only the root of the classpath is searched for the file